# How to set up a subnetwork at home for administering all routers?

Tags: networking, router

I have 3 routers. One is connected to the internet and the 2 others are connected to it. One router is my local network and the other should be guest network. My computer is connected to the local one.

- Is it possible for me to set up the network so that I can administer
  all routers from my computer and the guest network only to reach
  internet?
- How do I do it?

I try to find some book "local subnetwork for Dummys.." :-)

Comment: As for your last question - the book you're looking for is [**Networking for Dummies**](https://www.dummies.com/book/technology/information-technology/networking/general-networking/networking-for-dummies-12th-edition-281781/) :-D To give a proper advice how you could do it in your network, you should give more details: what exactly are the routers involved? How exactly are they connected (Router 1 LAN 4 port connects to Router 2 LAN 1 port...)? Please don't answer with a comment, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1768367/edit) your question instead.

Comment: For other very similar questions in the past, the answers have been 90% about basic IP routing, so if you're looking for a book, that's what you're looking for...